# Wait for something on the page to change in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to see when a page changes in selenium. It should detect when a new message popped up on the page.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(locator).Text != lastElement.Text);
```

Wait was recommended. I saw that this takes in a time parameter. unfortunately, I do not want the wait to time out ever. How would I do about implementing a system where selenium keeps listening for a change without timing out.

Comment: keep time to a large value

Comment: Or just keep it in a while loop and just break out of it if you want it to be infinite. This is only if it's the only thing in your program.

Comment: @PDHide Is there anyway to compare two strings instead of havign to use a find element?

I want something like this: wait.until(String x != stirng y);

Comment: That's a constant comparison that creates never ending loop what's your usecase

Comment: I just want it to wait until a new message is on the screen, then it will print to console when it detected a new message.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public static class WebDriverExtension
{
    public static IWebElement WaitForElement(this IWebDriver driver, By locator)
    {
      var wait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver)
      {
        PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250), // how many milliseconds you want to retry on element
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), // After how many secconds you want to time out, you can also use minutes.
        Message = $"My element timedout"
      };


      // Basically here it will loop through/retry every 250 milliseconds upto 30 seconds. 
      return wait.Until(e =>
       {
         var element = e.FindElement(locator);

         return (element.Displayed || element.Enabled) ? element : throw new NoSuchElementException(wait.Message);
       });
    }
}

// use
public class MyTestClass
{

[Test]
public void DriverTests(){
var driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.WaitForElement(By.id("blah")).Text;

driver.Quit();
}

}
```

Here is a reference in https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/explicit-fluent-wait-in-selenium-c/